# Netilat yadayim with liquid that an animal wouldn't drink

Tags: halacha, animals, netilat-yadayim-washing

The Shulchan Aruch writes ([Orach Hayim, 160: 8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.160.8?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) that the waters of Tveryah cannot be used for netilat yadayim because they are "bitter and not fitting for a dog to drink" (and presumably a human too). The Mishnah Berura writes ([160:37](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.160.37?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) that "even though they differ in taste from other waters that are not so suitable for human drinking, since they are still suitable for dogs to drink, they are fitting for netilat yadayim".

There are drinks that humans would drink and dogs wouldn't, and vice versa. For example, dogs wouldn't drink human wine or carbonated drinks. Humans wouldn't drink dirty/muddy water, whereas dogs would i.e., I have read the principle that "if an animal would drink it, then its ok for netliah", but there are plenty of human drinks that animals wouldn't drink. It works both ways.

Is the rule that as long as humans **or** dogs (or both) would drink it, then those drinks can be used for netilat yadayim?

Comment: *For example, dogs wouldn't drink human wine or carbonated drinks.* Wouldn't or shouldn't?

Comment: @shmosel i think wouldn't and shouldn't. These are examples i'm happy to amend. But something like whisky, dogs wouldn't go near it, let alone drink it.

Comment: Most humans wouldn't go near whiskey either, unless they've been brainwashed to think it's worth training their gag reflex into submission. Ask any child if whiskey is enjoyable..

Comment: @DoubleAA reminds me of a story of a Torah giant who, after his wife passed away and was offered the meal she made him for 70 years (macaroni and cheese), he declined saying he hates it, it reminded him of maggots he saw in the holocaust. They asked him why he ate it for 70 years and he said he didn't want to upset his wife. So training all of one's faculties into submission can serve goodness.

Comment: @Rabbi or it can serve a drug habit